# Validate URL with IsWellFormedOriginalString fails

Tags: c#, url

I want to Validate an URL. I first used `Uri.TryCreate`. But this creates a valid URL object for links with invalid special characters like this one: [https://www.z�rich.ch](https://www.z%EF%BF%BDrich.ch).
I therefore tried `IsWellFormedOriginalString` with the following result:

```
(new System.Uri("https://www.z�rich.ch")).IsWellFormedOriginalString().Display(); //false
(new System.Uri("https://www.google.ch?q=Schüler")).IsWellFormedOriginalString().Display(); //true
(new System.Uri("https://www.google.ch?q=Schuler%20Lehrer")).IsWellFormedOriginalString().Display(); //true
(new System.Uri("https://www.google.ch?q=Schüler%20Lehrer")).IsWellFormedOriginalString().Display(); //false
```

**Why is an URL with `ü` or `%20` correct and an URL with both (`ü` and `%20`) incorrect?**

Is there a method to validate the URLs above and only first case is invalid? I know, i can check for the `�` explicitly but maybe there is something more generic.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st URL contains a character that is not allowed in URLs. Of course it's clear it should be a u or ü but the string was probably converted from UTF-8 to an 8-bit encoding where the Unicode ü has no match in the target codepage.

In the case of the 4th URL, the %20 can be replaced with + to represent a space, which is the proper way to encode a space in the querystring. The ü is probably seen as indicating a different encoding than when such a character is absent.

Did you compose that 4th URL yourself? I'm wondering why there's a %20 instead of +, as when I follow the link and click Search, Google itself uses a + instead of %20 in the URL.

Comment: My Firefox displays "%20" as " " when I enter it into the url bar. The "ü" remains as is. But that might just be a display friendly feature.

Comment: All this examles i composed myself. You are right, with '+' and 'ü' it works. But I have the same problem when it is in the path insteat of the querystring:

(new System.Uri("https://www.google.ch/Schüler")).IsWellFormedOriginalString().Display(); //true
(new System.Uri("https://www.google.ch/Schuler%20Lehrer")).IsWellFormedOriginalString().Display(); //true
(new System.Uri("https://www.google.ch/Schüler%20Lehrer")).IsWellFormedOriginalString().Display(); //false

Even when you escape the 'ü' you got the same behavior.

Comment: @Thomas The URLs you would conceivably receive to validate would not have a structure like that, so for your actual task it shouldn't matter. But it's still interesting that `Uri.IsWellFormedOriginalString()` would behave this way.

The MSDN docs list a number of reasons why it would return false: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.iswellformedoriginalstring?view=net-6.0

Comment: Tto me the first reason (incorrectly escaped string) seems the most likely cause. I think `Sch%C3%BCler%20Lehrer` fails because it mixes 2 different encodings. `Sch%C3%BCler+Lehrer` however, does validate.